# Constructors as datatypes in Haskell

Tags: haskell

Currently I have these datatypes:

```
data NumberColumn = NumberColumn String [Double]
data StringColumn = StringColumn String [String]
data UnknownColumn = UnknownColumn String [String]
```

All of these datatypes (there are others too, these are just domain examples) model csv file columns. They can represent plain numbers, names, money, simple text and so on.

What I would like to achieve is something like this:

```
data Column = NumberColumn String [Double] | StringColumn String [String] | UnknownColumn String [String]
```

That is, I would like to put them in a single datatype so that it would be possible to map, filter and create new items, like so:

```
sumColumn :: NumberColumn -> NumberColumn -> NumberColumn
sumColumn...
```

The problem is that NumberColumn is not a datatype but a constructor, so the best that I can think of is to accept and return Column types:

```
sumColumn :: Column -> Column -> Column
sumColumn (NumberColumn...) (NumberColumn...)...
```

This works but the explicitness that the function should only take NumberColumns is lost and I would very much like to keep it.

Can this be achieved?

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you want a single type constructor `Column` defined as

```
data Column a = Column String [a]
```

Then

```
sumColumn :: Column Double -> Column Double -> Column Double
sumColumn (Column name values) = ...
```

To distinguish between `StringColumn` and `UnknownColumn` from your original, use a new type for `Unknown` to distinguish it from an "ordinary" string.

```
newtype Unknown = Unknown String

type UnknownColumn = Column Unknown  -- for example
```

Comment: I'm sorry if I'm missing something but how would this allow me to keep a list of different Columns?

Comment: It wasn't obvious from the question that was a requirement.

Comment: @PetrasPurlys Unfortunately those two features are incompatible: either the type system distinguishes the two things, so you can write a function which only accepts number columns, OR the type system does not distinguish the two things, so you can put them both in a list. If you want both features, you need two (collections of) types, one distinguishable and one not.

Comment: @PetrasPurlys You can move the `a` to the right and get back the power you wanted. `data Column = forall a. ToColumn a => Column a` (but then you'll lose and trace of `a` in type signatures)

Answer (score 0):

You could factor the `NumberColumn` constructor's data into a new datatype thusly:

```
data Column
    = NumberColumn  NumCol
    | StringColumn  String [String]
    | UnknownColumn String [String]

data NumCol = NumCol String [Double]
```

`sumColumn` is then defined over `NumCol`s only, rather than `Column`s or `NumberColumn`s:

```
sumColumn :: NumCol -> NumCol -> NumCol
sumColumn (NumCol s1 d1) (NumCol s2 d2) = ...
```

EDIT:

If you want `NumCol`s to behave like `NumberColumn`s, you could use a type class:

```
class Columnlike a where
    toColumn :: a -> Column

instance Columnlike Column where
    toColumn = id

instance Columnlike NumCol where
    toColumn = NumberColumn
```

With this type class at hand, your functions over `Column` can now be over some `Columnlike a`, and you can use `NumCol`s and `Column`s interchangeably. For example:

```
colFunction :: Column -> Column
colFunction = ...
```

becomes

```
colFunction :: Columnlike a => a -> a
colFunction = ...
```

and you can then use `colFunction` on `NumCol`s and `NumberColumn`s alike.

Comment: That would work but this is a matter of readability. NumCol and NumberColumn are/represent the same thing so I would very much like to have a single name.

Comment: @PetrasPurlys There is likely no free lunch there. You can, however, make `NumCol` and `NumberColumn` behave similarly, see my edit. Another option is to define `sumColumn` over pairs `(String, [Double])`, but this also has its downsides.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to chepner's

```
data Column a = Column String [a]
```

you could define `sumColumn` as

```
sumColumn :: Num a => Column a -> Column a -> Column a
sumColumn (Column name1 ms) (Column name2 ns) =
  Column (name1 ++ "+" ++ name2) (zipWith (+) ms ns)
```

You could also use GADTs to ensure that columns that contain numbers are only used as such:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}

data Column a where
  NumColumn :: Num a => String -> [a] -> Column a
  StrColumn :: String -> [String] -> Column String
```

but you'd still have to constrain every function that operates on `Num a => Column a`s.